# AngularJS update scope value on page on every loop

Tags: angularjs

What do I need to do to update the scope variable in the UI on every iteration of the loop in this example?

JS

```
var q = 100;
while ( q > 0 ) {
  $scope.someThing = q;
  q--;
}
```

HTML

```
{{someThing}}
```

I thought I was on to something with the following but it isn't working. All I see is the final result, not each iteration.

```
var q = 1000;
while ( q > 0 ) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.someThing = q;
      q--;
    });
}
```

--Edit--

Thanks for the suggestions on interval/timeout. I think I understand why this is needed now. But I was hoping I could "callback" the redraw somehow so the loop still runs as fast as possible. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: You would need to perform it in a `$timeout` basically you would need to make it async. loop runs synchronously. SO your loop completes running digest cycle happens and view gets updated with the result.

Comment: That loop executes *extremely* fast - you won't see it count up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to do it async with a timeout between each iteration.
I'd use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) for this:

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {

  var q = 100;
  var interval = $interval(decreaseQ, 50);
  
  function decreaseQ() {
    $scope.someThing = q;
    
    if(q == 0) $interval.cancel(interval);
    else q--;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  {{someThing}}
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, it's hard to choose which answer to mark correct when there are multiple answers that are similar.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>That loop executes extremely fast - you won't see it count up.</strike>  Thanks to @PSL for a better explanation: Basically JavaScript loop runs synchronously. And Angular depends upon the digest cycle to update the view based on the scope property. In this case loop runs and then digest cycle happens. You would instead need to let the digest cycle happen after every count in order to see progressive update.

Use a `$timeout` if you want it to work:

```
var q = 100;

function subtractQ() {
    q--;
    $scope.someThing = q;
}

$timeout(subtractQ, 1000);
```

Or `$interval`

```
$interval(function() {
    q--;
    $scope.someThing = q;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It really not just about it running extremely fast. Basically javascipt loop is synchronous. And angular depends upon the digest cycle to update the view based on the scope property. In this case loop runs and then digest cycle happens.

Comment: So is there has to be some sort of delay in order for it to be redrawn on the UI? That seems like it would slow things down unnecessarily. Can't I "callback" the redraw somehow so it runs as fast as possible?

Comment: @PSL -- Much better explanation - added it to my answer.

Comment: @xdaxdb -- What is your overall goal - I thought it was to have a countdown the user could see, is there a different purpose?

Comment: In my actual application I am trying to write, there is a mathematical/statistical experiment running in a loop. I want to display the results as they happen. I want it to run as fast as possible while also making the results change rapidly on the page.

Comment: @xdaxdb -- Change the `timeout` or `interval` to `1` then and it will run fast - you may not *see* any of the changes since the speed of the loop will be so great.

Comment: @xdaxdb One thing you would need to understand is Javascript cannot run 2 scripts at the same time. Here you would need digest cycle to happen after each iteration of the loop. Though you can use [HTML5 worker threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage#Browser_compatibility) in newer browsers to create thread. Simplest approach would be just to use timeout or interval.

Answer (score 1):

You could try $timeout instead of the while loop to delay the function.

Something like this:

```
 $timeout(function(){
    $scope.something = q;
    q--;
  }, 1000);
```